# nightwatch.js pausing at the end of test suite

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I've been using **`nightwatch.js`** for functional test automation. The problem is that the test is pausing when the test suite is finished. It doesn't end the process. The code looks like this :

```
var afterSuite = function(browser) {
    dbFixture.deleteCollectionItemById(companyId, 'cilents');
    dbFixture.deleteCollectionItemById(customerId, 'users');
    dbFixture.deleteCollectionItemById(assetId, 'assets');
    dbFixture.deleteFile(imageId);
    browser.end();
};

var loginTest = function(browser) {
    dbFixture.createCompany(function(company) {
        dbFixture.createCustomer(company._id, function(customer, assetid, imageid) {
            companyId = company._id;
            customerId = customer._id;
            assetId = assetid;
            imageId = imageid;
            goTo.goTo(url.localhost_home + url.login, browser);
            login.loginAsAny(customer.email, browser);
            newCustomerLoginAssert.assertNewCustomerLogin(browser);
        });
    });
};

module.exports = {
    after: afterSuite,
    'As a Customer, I should be able to login to the system once my registration has been approved': loginTest
};
```

I also tried adding **`done();`** in **`afterSuite`** but still no success. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An approach is to register a global `reporter` function that is run once all tests have finished and exits the process accordingly ie. if tests have failed or errored, `exit 1`, otherwise `exit 0`.

eg. http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#external-globals

In your `nightwatch.json` config add:

```
{
  "globals_path": "./config/global.js"
}
```

Then in `./config/global.js`

```
module.exports = {
    /**
     * After all the tests are run, evaluate if there were errors and exit appropriately.
     *
     * If there were failures or errors, exit 1, else exit 0.
     *
     * @param results
     */
    reporter: function(results) {
        if ((typeof(results.failed) === 'undefined' || results.failed === 0) &&
        (typeof(results.error) === 'undefined' || results.error === 0)) {
            process.exit(0);
        } else {
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

What was the root cause of this issue?

Using Josh's approach solves the issue, but then I'm not getting a junit report anymore.

Answer (score 1):

in the latest `global.js` script, is a tiny bug ... the property name is error**s**.

```
module.exports = {
  /**
   * After all the tests are run, evaluate if there were errors and exit appropriately.
   *
   * If there were failures or errors, exit 1, else exit 0.
   *
   * @param results
   */
  reporter: function(results) {
    if (
      (typeof results.failed === 'undefined' || results.failed === 0) &&
      (typeof results.errors === 'undefined' || results.errors === 0)
    ) {
      process.exit(0);
    } else {
      process.exit(1);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.

Comment: This worked for me. I am using a tricky setup where I have a C# API which when called uses Hangfire to call a .bat file that then fires off nightwatch tests.
Without this code in my global.js the Hangfire task never finishes. This code looks for 'errors' and 'failed' props in the results that get passed to the reporter at the end of testing and kills the process.

Comment: The reason for the C# API is because our site takes 10+ minutes to come up after a push so triggering NW right away wasn't working.
We are planning to add something in our site that when it comes live, it will reach out to the API to trigger the NW testing.

Answer (score 0):

Small tweak over Martin Oppitz's answer; `setTimeout` is necessary to give webdriver time to terminate. Otherwise, running it again will give a race condition.

```
// test/reporter.js
const reporter = new HtmlReporter({
  reportsDirectory: 'test/reports',
});

module.exports = {
  write: function(results, options, done) {

    const hasFailure =
      (typeof results.failed !== 'undefined' && results.failed !== 0) ||
      (typeof results.errors !== 'undefined' && results.errors !== 0);

    const _forceExit = () => {
      done();
    // setTimeout is neccessary to give webdriver time to terminate.
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (hasFailure) {
          return process.exit(1);
        }
        return process.exit(0);
      }, 1000);
    };

    reporter.fn(results, _forceExit);
  },
};
```

This can be run via `nightwatch --reporter test/reporter.js`.